# How to Create a Wide Table with Automatic Line Breaks and Repeating Row Headers

Tags: tables, longtable, xtab

I want to create a comparison table in LaTeX similar to [those that can be found on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages).
I basically want the behavior of `longtable` or rather `xtab` or another package, as the former does not work with `multicol`, of wrapping the table automatically and repeating the column header after wrap but with the first row as row header additionally.

In addition, I want to group several column headings, basically properties, under multi-column headings that represent those properties' categories.
The table should, in the best case, break at the category boundary.

This is an example such a table without breaks:
[image: Example of the desired table design]

How can I achieve this in LaTeX?

The packages `longtable`, `supertabular` and `xtab`, all of which I tried, only seem to support column headings but no row headings.
I guess I am more asking for package recommendations at this point.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: I updated my question, `longtable`, `supertabular` and `xtab`.

Comment: As your table is (currently) very wide and not very high, it will most likely not fit on a page. If I understood you correctly you want to circumvent this by putting (e.g.) category 1 in the first row, and then categories 2 and 3 into another row? This sounds quite weird to me. Would pivoting your table be an option (i.e. exchange rows and columns)?

Comment: I sadly can't show the actual table/data, so I had to create a very generic table. From a readability standpoint I would prefer it like I outlined it in my question. If it really does not work out like I wanted it to, that will be my last option.

Comment: Please show us a code for your table. that we no need to rewrite it from scratch. Is rotate table in landscape an option?